# How to run a retry when download fails in AsyncTask using AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, service, android-asynctask, alarmmanager

I use an `AlarmManager` to run a Service which tries to download a file from the web. If it fails I'd like to retry that Service in 5 minutes.

Inside the Service I run an `AsyncTask` to run my code. As far as I know the only way I can tell if it failed or not is from the `onPostExecute()`.

What is the best way of implementing a retry of that Service again?

Comment: If it failed, add a one time alarm to restart the service. How often does the alarmanager run the service normally?

Comment: @Falmarri `AlarmManager` runs at a set interval chosen by user (e.g. 30 minutes, 1 hour, 1 day etc). The problem is the `AlarmManager`is started from one class but the AsyncTask is in another class, therefore the class that starts the `AlarmManager` doesn't know whether it has failed or not. I don't want to start an `AlarmManager` from the `onPostExecute()` of my Service class.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to start an alarmmanager from onpostexecute()? You could use a timertask if you don't want to use an alarmmanager

Comment: @Falmarri If I start an `AlarmManager` from within the Service then I'm sort of creating a recurring function where I'm calling the Service from itself. Is there a way I could implement a handler to send back and pass or fail?

Comment: I meant you can conditionally recall the alarmmanager if it fails. Create a separate alarm that isn't recurring to reschedule the service in 5 minutes. By your service failing, I assume you mean it failed to download the file, not failed as in android killed it, right?

Comment: Correct, the download failed. Could you show me some code to recall the `AlarmManager`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falmarri's answer is the correct one, and I do not understand your concerns.

In `onPostExecute()`, when you determine that things went awry:

1. Call `getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE)` to get the `AlarmManager`
2. Call `set()` on the `AlarmManager` to trigger you in 5 minutes

If needed, use extras on the `Intent` in the `PendingIntent` to give you information about what to retry, or use a custom action string to distinguish retries from the scheduled alarm, or something. Note that if you use `Intent` extras, you will need to choose an appropriate flag with `PendingIntent` (e.g., `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`).

> The problem is the AlarmManager is started from one class but the AsyncTask is in another class, therefore
>   the class that starts the AlarmManager doesn't know whether it has failed or not.

So? Multiple classes can talk to the `AlarmManager`. Also, feel free to pass data to your `AsyncTask` subclass via its constructor.

Also, you might want to consider using an `IntentService` rather than a `Service` and `AsyncTask`. `IntentService` gives you a background thread automatically. Plus, it shuts down when there is no more work to be done, which is also important, so you don't get a bunch of one-star ratings on the Market complaining about the service you keep running all of the time.

> I don't want to start an AlarmManager from the onPostExecute() of my Service class.

Why not?

> If I start an AlarmManager from within the Service then I'm sort of creating a recurring function where
>   I'm calling the Service from itself.

Of course. That's what you want. It matters not a whit whether the `Service` or the `AsyncTask` or the `MyOtherReallyCoolClass` is the one actually talking to `AlarmManager` -- the component that is rescheduling the `Service` is the `Service` itself.