# Best java practice for retrying asynctask (android)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a base abstract class that all my asynctasks extend from. I have built in error handling for network errors where I display a dialog to the user telling them they can retry their request (after all it was a network error...).

I am having a bit of a problem "retrying" my asynctask since once it is executed, you cannot execute it again. How could I go by do that ? Should I use reflection to instantiate the same class and retry?

Has anyone dealt with this problem before?

Comment: Perhaps you could post the code for your current error handling?

Answer (score 1):

here seems to be the answer you need:

[How to run a retry when download fails in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693672/how-to-run-a-retry-when-download-fails-in-asynctask-using-alarmmanager)

Comment: Does not really help me as I do not want to use an IntentService or Service for these tasks. I want to avoid binding for getting the results or use a ResultReceiver + IntentService. I am having a hard time to re-instantiate the same asynctask and call execute() on it.

Answer (score 1):

[AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) are single use and can only be executed once. An exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted. The solution is just create a new AsyncTask and execute it.

Comment: Yes, I know that but how would you go by and recreate it automatically for all asynctasks. I want this logic to be hidden and automatically happen for me when the user clicks 'Retry' no matter what type of task it is.